# Pegar partes de um vetor JSON

Tags: restful, react

Estou com duvida na função GET do meu codigo JS (React JS), tenho a função GET utilizando a api Fetch, ela retorna os valores um certo link.json contendo uma array. Usando como exemplo esse link: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts - Eu quero pegar o conteudo do primeiro 'Id'(1) e colocar numa parte do codigo, e tambem outro 'Id'(Exemplo: 5) qualquer da array para outra parte do codigo.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      data:[]
      }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
        let URL = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'

           fetch(URL)
           .then(function(response) {
              let data = response.json()
              return data;
           })
           .then((json) => {
              console.log('mensagens: ', json)
              this.setState({data : json});
           })
           .catch(function(ex) {
              console.log('parsing failed', ex)
           })
  }
```

ATUALIZAÇÃO:

```
      {
         this.state.data.map(obj => (
           if(obj.displayPortraitLeft == true){
             <div className="box-body">
            <div className="direct-chat-msg undefined">
                      <div className="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                      <span className="direct-chat-name pull-right">{obj.userName}</span>
                      <span className="direct-chat-timestamp pull-left">{obj.time}</span>
                      </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           }else{
               <div className="box-body">
            <div className="direct-chat-msg undefined">
                      <div className="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                      <span className="direct-chat-name pull-right">{obj.userName}</span>
                      <span className="direct-chat-timestamp pull-left">{obj.time}</span>
                      </div>
               </div>
             </div>
         ))
     }
```

Retorna no navegador : ./src/chat/Chat.js
Syntax error: C:/Users/henri/Desktop/funcionando/my-app/src/chat/Chat.js: Unexpected token (41:19)

```
  39 |              {
  40 |                  this.state.data.map(obj => (
> 41 |                    if(obj.displayPortraitLeft == true){
     |                    ^
  42 |                      <div>
  43 |                      <div className="box-body">
  44 |
```

Comment: Oi Henrique. Conseguiste resolver a pergunta de CSS de ontem?

Comment: Consegui a parte da posição de cada widget em diferentes tamanhos de tela, tipo: Telas pequenas um abaixo do outro, Telas Medias, 2 colunas e 2 Linhas...

Comment: Ok, se ainda não tiveres tudo resolvido junta o resto do HTML ou JSX lá para podermos ajudar. Respondi aqui a esta pergunta entretanto, vê se faz sentido e é isso que procuras. Nas outras perguntas vejo que estás a usar outros componentes, aqui dei exemplo com html mais simples.

Comment: Henrique, você pode simplificar seu IF ja linha 41. Se o valor do obj.displayPortraitLeft é true ou false, você pode deixar só `if (obj.displayPortraitLeft)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer isso assim, usando o `this.state.data` como array que é e iterando com `map` para gerar JSX

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
        let URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
           fetch(URL)
           .then(function(response) {
              let data = response.json()
              return data;
           })
           .then((json) => {
              console.log('mensagens: ', json)
              this.setState({data : json});
           })
           .catch(function(ex) {
              console.log('parsing failed', ex)
           })
  }
  render(){
      return (
          <div>
            {
                this.state.data.map(obj => (
                  <div>{obj.id} {obj.title}</div>
                ))
            }
          </div>
      );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Ok, nesse sentido consegui fazer rodar, mas se por exemplo eu queira pegar so a terceira frase do teu comentario "3 ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut", qual sintaxe utilizado para manipular o vetor JSON?

Comment: @HenriqueHermes onde tens a informação que é só a id3? é um input? ou está no `this.state.filtro: [3, 5]` por exemplo?

Comment: Vamos imaginar o seguinte, eu tenho um array em JSON, varios elementos inseridos: [ { "userId": 1 } { "userId": 122 } { "userId": 133 } ] e eu queria pegar somente o valor '122' do "userID"

Comment: @HenriqueHermes nesse caso podias fazer `arr[1].userId` mas isso é demasiado específico, não creio que seja isso que precisas... No exemplo de cima o `fetch` traz vários posts. Onde no código sabes que é o `3` que queres mostrar? é `state`? ou `prop` ou um `<input>`?

Comment: é que estou desenvolvendo um 'chat', onde eu ja inicio ele com mensagens inseridas, e o JSON que estou pegando essas mensagens, estão em formato Array, nesse JSON tenho 2 usuarios, e cada usuario tem 2 ou 3 mensagens prontas, se eu utilizar esse codigo acima ele pega todos os conteudos passados pela chave, em java eu utilizaria algo semelhante a arrayJson[2].mensagem  -> Imagem do chat a ser desenvolvido https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/capture-png--215

Comment: @HenriqueHermes então e sabes os IDs dessas mensagens já pré-inseridas?

Comment: No codigo JS, eu colocaria a especifica mensagem aqui:   <div className="direct-chat-text"> MENSAGEM DO VETOR da posiçao [x]  </div>

Comment: @HenriqueHermes sim, isso é simples, mas sabes o valor de `x`?

Comment: Sei os valores, no console.log irei me guiar pelo userName. https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/capture-png--216  ---- Cada linha desse vetor, contem uma mensagem

Comment: @HenriqueHermes então queres só mostrar as mensagens que tenham um certo `userName` é isso?

Comment: Mais ou menos isso, o sentido é igual aos comentarios nossos aqui no stackOverflow, uma fica abaixo da outra, a minha mensagem corresponde a posição [0] do vetor JSON, e a sua na posição [1], a seguinte [2] .. [3] etc, eu quero que o codigo js que estou desenvolvendo, leia por primeiro somente o conteudo da posição [0], e printe num campo do chat, abaixo dele quero que faça a mesma coisa, so que somente com o conteudo da posição [1]

Comment: @HenriqueHermes mas no exemplo que dei faz isso, imprime do `[0]` até ao fim da array. Mas mais do que isso queres que só imprima se tiver `user == 'Mary'` ou `user == 'John'`? estou meio perdido ainda com o que queres fazer...

Comment: Você esta certo, verifiquei aqui o codigo e realizei umas alterações, esta funcionando corretamente.

Comment: @HenriqueHermes ótimo!

Comment: eu consigo fazer comparação utilizando os dados do vetor JSON? tenho um campo com "displayPortraitLeft":false -- eu consigo fazer uma comparaçao no .JS com IF e ELSE? No sentido de se "displayPortraitLeft" for igual a false, utilize um CSS diferente do que "displayPortraitLeft" igual a true

Comment: if({obj.displayPortraitLeft} == false){
  Algum codigo qualquer que utilizara uma classe com padding para direita
}else {   Algum codigo qualquer que utilizara uma classe com padding para esquerda }

Comment: @HenriqueHermes sim. Deveria ser `f(obj.displayPortraitLeft == false){` sem `{}`.

Comment: Coloquei na pergunta, um erro que esta aparecendo no meu navegador, não detectei o que esta de errado

Comment: @HenriqueHermes evita mudar a pergunta. Assim a minha resposta ao assunto específico fica sem sentido. Se tiveres problemas faz uma pergunta nova. Nesse caso tens `obj => (` e devia ser `obj => {` e depois `}` no final dessa callback.

Comment: Ok, abri uma nova pergunta, caso queria verificar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/252683/condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-if-else-reactjs-json